# How set the same header / footer fo all pages in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr, samepage

i want to set the same header in all pages in my LaTeX book.
Is it possibile to put draw, tikzpicture or external pictures?

Thanks!!

I'm using this

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
```

Comment: try `\makeatletter\let\ps@plain\ps@headings\let\ps@empty\ps@headings\makeatother` in your preamble

Comment: use package `fancyhdr` or `scrlayer-scrpage` and define the headers.

Comment: @Lupino your code is usefull for an other problems ...